# Overflow:hidden and border-radius not working with css-animation

Tags: css, animation, overflow, border

I'm having trouble with what I believe is a bug in Safari, every other Browser shows it correctly.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvavVa

html looks like this:

```
<div id="background"></div>
<div id="midground"><div id="baggy"></div></div>
```

CSS like this:

```
@keyframes ex4 { /* CSS3 */
0%   { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
-moz-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
-ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
-o-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
transform: translate(0px, 0px); }
100% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, -5000px);
-moz-transform: translate(0px, -5000px);
-ms-transform: translate(0px, -5000px);
-o-transform: translate(0px, -5000px);
transform: translate(0px, -5000px); } }

@-moz-keyframes ex4 { /* CSS3 */
0%   { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
-moz-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
-ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
-o-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
transform: translate(0px, 0px); }
100% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, -5000px);
-moz-transform: translate(0px, -5000px);
-ms-transform: translate(0px, -5000px);
-o-transform: translate(0px, -5000px);
transform: translate(0px, -5000px); } }

@-webkit-keyframes ex4 { /* CSS3 */
0%   { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
-moz-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
-ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
-o-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
transform: translate(0px, 0px); }
100% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 5000px);
-moz-transform: translate(0px, -5000px);
-ms-transform: translate(0px, -5000px);
-o-transform: translate(0px, -5000px);
transform: translate(0px, -5000px); } }
}





body { 
font: 10px/2 "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
position: absolute;
top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
}

#background {
background: url("http://epicstudios.de/blackwhite/bg2.jpg") fixed repeat;  
-webkit-background-size: 100vw auto;
-moz-background-size: 100vw auto;
-o-background-size: 100vw auto;
background-size: 100vw auto;
position: absolute;
background-position:center top;
height:400vh;
top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
z-index: 100
;z-index: 199;

animation:         ex4 150s infinite; /* CSS3 */
-moz-animation:    ex4 150s infinite; /* Firefox */
-webkit-animation: ex4 150s infinite; /* Webkit */
}

#midground {
width:240px;
height:240px;
position:absolute;
left:0px; right:0px;
top:0; bottom:0;
margin:auto;
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;
overflow:auto;
border-radius:500px;    
z-index:200;    
overflow:hidden;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
     -o-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
        transition: all 0.7s ease-out;

}

#midground:hover {

width:350px;
height:350px;
position:absolute;
left:0px; right:0px;
top:0px; bottom:0;
margin:auto;
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;
overflow:hidden;
border-radius:0px;  
z-index:200;
}





#baggy {        background: url(http://epicstudios.de/blackwhite        /bg_neg.jpg) repeat fixed;   
background-position:center top; -webkit-background-size: 100vw auto;
-moz-background-size: 100vw auto;
-o-background-size: 100vw auto;
background-size: 100vw auto;
background-repeat: repeat-y;
height:600vh;
position:absolute;
left:0; right:0;
top:0; bottom:0;
margin:auto;

overflow:hidden;    z-index: 201;animation:         ex4 150s infinite;  /* CSS3 */
-moz-animation:    ex4 150s infinite; /* Firefox */
-webkit-animation: ex4 150s infinite; /* Webkit */
}
```

The div in the center there should be a Circle, but safari shows a square. In this circle there's a div, that is larger than the circle and is moving because of a css-animation. As soon as I apply this animation to that div, the `overflow:hidden` and/or the `border-radius:50%` of the circle-div above it stop working and it appears as a square in safari.

I hope that's clear. I can't use JavaScript for the animation because I tried that before, and it worked, but it proved to be too difficult to process on most computers and the site started lagging and stuttering heavily.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvavVa

Comment: showed us the code so that we can figure an answer out for you

Comment: I have added Code and a simple codepen, hopefully that will help!